# I want the table to be sorted in a particular order on load using tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I have a table which displays like this when I load the page. [image]

But I want the subjects to be in a particular order(math,history,science and physics) but the professor names should be sorted in ascending order.[image]

Can this be done using tablesorter's custom sort?

```js
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>subject</th>
      <th>professor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>math</td>
      <td>Jordan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>math</td>
      <td>Kent</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>math</td>
      <td>Wayne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>history</td>
      <td>Richards</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>history</td>
      <td>Xavier</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>science</td>
      <td>Arthur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>science</td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>physics</td>
      <td>Steve</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>physics</td>
      <td>Wade</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ritesh26/6w9y2r0p/14/)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Jquery Datatable ?

Comment: @Dilip, the OP is using `tablesorter` check the CDN links provided

Comment: are there more subjects ? or these are the ones ?

Comment: @Dilip I used tablesorter.

Comment: @Towkir These are the only ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a custom sort order you should add your own parser. Check [this](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html) example in the docs.

Then, to order by default both columns, just pass [`sortList`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#sortlist) to your configuration object.

And to add an additional forced sort that will be appended to the dynamic selections by the user use [`sortAppend`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#sortappend).

Note that in the snippet below I have switched "Steve" and "Wade" so you can see that the `sortList` is working.

```js
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  // set a unique id
  id: 'subjects',
  is: function(s, table, cell, $cell) {
    // return false so this parser is not auto detected
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
    // format your data for normalization
    return s.toLowerCase()
      .replace(/math/,0)
      .replace(/history/,1)
      .replace(/science/,2)
      .replace(/physics/,3);
  },
  // set type, either numeric or text
  type: 'numeric'
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue', 
    sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]],
    sortAppend : [[1,0]]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>


<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorter-subjects">subject</th>
      <th>professor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>math</td>
      <td>Jordan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>math</td>
      <td>Kent</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>math</td>
      <td>Wayne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>history</td>
      <td>Richards</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>history</td>
      <td>Xavier</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>science</td>
      <td>Arthur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>science</td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>physics</td>
      <td>Wade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>physics</td>
      <td>Steve</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the help and explanation.